# Multiple function plots with hold on

Tags: matlab, plot

With the following code, I am able to draw two plots via the `hold on` command.

```
x=0:0.1:10;
r1 = 1;
y1=r1 * x .^ 2;
plot( x, y1 );
hold on;
r2 = 1.5;
y2=r2 * x .^ 2;
plot( x, y2 );
```

However, I am looking for a way to define `r=1:0.5:2` and plot three diagrams in one plot. Something like this

```
x=0:0.1:10;
r=1:0.5:2;
y=r * x .^ 2;
plot( x, y );
hold on;
```

But it is not correct due to the matrix multiplications.

The problem is related to inner matrix dimensions, e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778027). But mine seems to be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close.  There are two ways to do what you want.  The first way is to use a loop and loop over each parameter of `r` and plot your points.  The second way (which is more elegant to me) is to create a matrix of points and plot all of those simultaneously - one plot for each value of `r`.  Let's start with the first approach:

## Using a loop

Simply iterate over each value of `r` and plot it:

```
x=0:0.1:10;
for r = 1:0.5:2 % Change
    y=r * x .^ 2;
    plot( x, y );
    hold on;
end
```

As you can see, the only change you need to make is to change the `r` statement into a `for` loop.  This way, we will plot three graphs on the same plot with three different colours automatically.

## Creating a matrix of points

A way to do this rather elegantly is to perform multiplication and broadcasting.  Specifically, square each element of `x`, transpose it then use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) combined with the `times` function to perform element-wise multiplication so that you can create a matrix of three columns - each column defines the points of `x` evaluated for each value of `r`.  You can plot all graphs simultaneously defined within this matrix of points with one `plot` call.

In other words:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
r = 1:0.5:2;
y = bsxfun(@times, r, (x.^2).');
plot(x, y);
```

In MATLAB R2016b and up, you can perform this multiplication natively and it will broadcast internally:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
r = 1:0.5:2;
y = r * (x.^2).';
plot(x, y);
```

Comment: Many thanks. The first one is straightforward. Regarding the legend, the `plot( x, y, 'DisplayName', r );  legend ('show');`, is not correct since I used variable `r`. How can display the value of `r` at each iteration?

Comment: @mahmood Add a legend at the end of the loop.  Therefore, just use `plot(x, y)` then at the very end of the code, do something like this: `legend(sprintfc('r=%.2f', r));`

Comment: But it only prints for the last `r` which is `2.0`.

Comment: @mahmood Oh I'm sorry.  `r` is not a vector in your case.  Please do this: `legend(sprintfc('r=%.2f', 1:0.5:2));`  You must do it this way if you use the `for` loop.  If you use the second method, then you can just do: `legend(sprintfc('r=%.2f', r));`.