# How to fix ‘Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab-guide

```
s = 1000;
t = linspace(0,1,Fs);
x = cos(2*pi*100*t)+0.5.*randn(size(t));
fc = 150;
Wn = (2/Fs).*fc;
b = fir1(20,Wn,'low',kaiser(21,3));
```

//Error using  * 
//Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778027/inner-matrix-dimensions-must-agree
```

Comment: someone suggested the change it to "." i.e y = exp(-x) * sin(x); like y = exp(-x) .* sin(x); but still the same error.... can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is an element wise operator, `randn(n)` returns an array of size n, 0.5 is a scalar, matlab doesn't auto broadcast like numpy.

If you want each element to be multiplied by 0.5, you can directly do that, and if you have to use broadcasting look into the fuction `bsxfun(fun,A,B)`, however `bsxfun` is prone to memory issues, so be careful. But it has powerful implicit expansion enabled.

To learn more about `bsxfun` visit https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html

If this doesn't solve your issue, you might need to supply a bit more of your code or variable information present in the workspace.

P.S: Broadcasting is generally referred as expansion in matlab documents and it comes from the fact that  the smaller array is “broadcast” or "expanded" across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes. In most cases this expansion is purely symbolic and doesn't actually put more variables in the scope, but just repeats(re-uses) the variables present.

Comment: Error in Untitled3 (line 8)
b = fir1(20,Wn,'low',kaiser(21,3));      i didnt find the error in the code while it Error in firls (line 81)
    cos_ints = [omega; sin((1:N)' * omega)]

Comment: Can you print shape of all the matrices before that statement, also if you have updated your code, then the updates that you made?

Comment: open Matlab--> Help-->  Signal processing Toolbox ---> Tutorials --->Filtering Data With Signal Processing Toolbox Software, i am learning ,, when i am trying to run their code , its give me above error

Comment: I believe this is the code you are talking about https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/filtering-data-with-signal-processing-toolbox.html

Comment: Works in my system, have you used rng default?